# Ubuntu Arabic font became too ugly after upgrade

Tags: gnome, upgrade, fonts

After I upgraded my distribution, the Arabic font changed and became too ugly (for the the system, the web browsers, all file managers, all interfaces (gnome and cinnamon)  and everything).

I already searched for an answer here, this question have been asked before
for example:
[System font is too small](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577119/system-font-is-too-small)
[Arabic font ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978509/arabic-font-ubuntu-17-10)

But neither seemed to have an answer (I tried all the suggestions in the comments)

I had this problem before, and I know that creating a new user account or using `dconf reset -f` will do it, but I don't want to reset my account and lose all my modifications each time I upgrade.

I need the `dconf` command to reset the fonts only, I think this will solve it.

Also, gnome tweak tool only changes the English font, but it doesn't help with any other language (I hope someone can create a tool that can customize all the fonts of all languages)

Comment: anythign that worked?

Comment: No, had to reinstall the whole thing